# Explicit call to a template class method : confusion with binary operator <

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template base class `Base` that implements a
non-type template `<int I>` method called `toto()`.

```
template<typename T>
class Base{ 
public:
  template<int I>
  void toto(){
  }
};
```

I also have a derived class, which calls `toto()` in a method `use_toto()` :

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> { 
public:
  void use_toto(){
    this->toto<1>();
  }
};
```

To call `toto()` I  use the `this` pointor. Because I use template classes, this is a way to avoid the so-called *[two-stage (or dependent) name lookup](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/gcc/Name-lookup.html)* issue. If I were calling directly `toto<1>()` I would get a *non declared* error.

The problem is that when I'm calling the method like this :

```
int main() 
{
  Derived<int> A;
  A.use_toto();
}
```

I have this kind of error :

> error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>‘ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’

Actually, in `this->toto<1>();` there is a confusion between the template symbol `<` and the *less than* operator.

Comment: You need `template` keyword to tell that `toto` is a template, e.g. `this->template toto<1>();`.